# Error In Core File

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

In my cart (expresso-store), this error (underneath) gets displayed at the top of my page for every product in my cart i.e. if I have 2 products, 2 of these gets displayed, if I have 5 products in the cart, 5 of these gets displayed underneath each other. Is this a common mistake or am I missing something in my list of products in my code?

I am using the `{exp:channel:entries}` and `{items}` tags to iterate through the carts products.

[image: Error In Core File]

Comment: We'll need more info then that to try and narrow it down. That definitely isn't default behaviour in any version right up to the latest so there must be something else at work here either in your templates or in any custom extensions or development work you've added. Start with just the defaults and test with the default templates and add any customisations until it throws the error.

Comment: Fixed this. I had `{if modifiers}` and then displayed the modifiers. I changed this to `{if modifier_name}`. Seems like this fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. It could be worth writing that up as an answer and accepting just so it closes off the thread with a successful resolution. You'll need to wait a few days to accept your own answer however or I can write it up for you if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. I had `{if modifiers}` and then displayed the modifiers. I changed this to `{if modifier_name}`. Seems like this fixed the problem.